# Google Maps Api in CRM Dynamics 2011 iframe. "Impossible to use display property" message

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm tring to use the google maps api inside CRM Dynamics 2011.

It was going well before I return to holiday.
After that, I have always this error: Impossible to obtain the display property. Argument not valid.

This error looks inside main.js of google maps apis.

I believed that the error was for the missed doctype, but after I put it but the error continue.

Someone have any idea? Ty

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587238/google-maps-api-v3-19-broken-in-ie11

Answer (score 0):

Please use this JS API include in the script of your frame page :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&libraries=geometry

(this replace the older called URL : maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false)

It seems to fix the problem.

In fact, Google Maps release version changes on 15th February to 3.18:
developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning

Vincent.