# Script errors when loading maps

Tags: delphi, gmlib

As of today, the delphi component has been returning script errors when trying to load the map.  We have not changed any code in the application or component.
Have Google changed something in their API?  If so, is there a new version of the component to deal with this?
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I have done a test and here (Spain/Andorra) works fine. What's the error message?

Answer (score 2):

See my question [Google Maps API v3.19 Broken in Internet Explorer Quirks Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587238/google-maps-api-v3-19-broken-in-ie11)

I suspect you have the same issue - note the comment 'This worked in my case, which was an embedded TWebBrowser inside of a Delphi project' from the user [FLDelphi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775909/fldelphi)

Comment: Thanks Elliveny.  We are using the google recommended delphi component, GMLib. I think the actual browser component is called TGMMap so we'll have to have a dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a resolution to this via [Google Maps API v3.19 Broken in Internet Explorer Quirks Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587238/google-maps-api-v3-19-broken-in-ie11/28606374#28606374)

Within the resource files of the GMLib component we found a map.html file.
We added the following line to the  section of the html file.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

We then recompiled the resource files into the component, recompiled the delphi project and it worked.

I suppose this is one of the downsides of using relatively unsupported free components.

We are now considering moving to a commercial paid for google maps component to reduce the risk of this happening again.

Comment: Why do you say *relatively unsupported* when the author himself asked you something under your question and you just ignored him ? Proper way would be [`reporting this issue`](https://code.google.com/p/gmlibrary/issues/list). Besides, if this problem arised just a few hours or days ago, how quickly do you expect a paid component authors like TMS will react to that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use old api like this :

just add "v=3&"

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>