# Is Google map v2 service still works

Tags: google-maps

I use Google maps ver 2 API. Its worked  till 17/02/2015. I tried different keyes. But I can't load the map. I keep getting "could not get display property.
invalid argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3.19 Broken in Internet Explorer Quirks Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587238/google-maps-api-v3-19-broken-in-internet-explorer-quirks-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I read in another post that Api v3 had the same issue. It was resolved changing version number....