# WebBrowser Delphi does not work Google Maps

Tags: javascript, delphi, google-maps-api-3

I have webbrowser that navigates to page: [poligono](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/polygon-simple?hl=pt-br)

With chrome ok - In Delphi does not show anything.

```
unit Unit11;

procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/polygon-simple?hl=pt-br');
```

Comment: I understand that you might be new on StackOverflow but I would suggest you try to get your post sorted to be a bit more readable. The "enter image description" and link tags make your post a bit difficult to understand. Some of the more unforgiving guys on stackoverflow might get into a moderator fit and downvote your question and even close it. And there is no need for that. We want to help as much as we can.

Comment: You probably also need to opt in to get modern rendering and not some dire ie compat mode, BrowserEmulation reg setting iirc

Comment: Google needs to update their examples by what is shown e.g. [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28589626/960757). I can confirm that if you add that `meta` line, it starts to work.

Comment: There is a nice post which David has answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843845/how-to-have-delphi-twebbrowser-component-running-in-ie9-mode. It might not be your solution but if so then upvote David's answer there.

Comment: @BlurrySterk, as first the OP should stop using an offsite example script (in *production* code) and make their own. Then they can request a compatibility mode of their choice in the script.

Comment: @TLama. I see what you mean.

Comment: The reason why OP does get blank page is becouse by default TWebBrowser opens web pages in compatibility mode. You can test this by opening the linked page in IE (and it will be nicely shown). But if you enable the compatibility mode for that page you will end up with the blank page as the OP does. So David Heffernans answer that Blue Sterk suggested should work. But perhaps even better solution would be to use Delphi Chromium instead of TWebBrowser.